# Javascript Drag and Drop event - error catching

Tags: javascript, error-handling, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to catch errors for Drag and Drop events?

To give you more context, on Windows 10, if I try dropping a file, with a path + filename of more than 1000 characters in length, dropping doesn't work. File just disappears.

(If said files path + filename is less than 1000 chars, everything works fine).

`DataTransferItem` has a limit of 1000 chars, so I want to inform the user that the file's path + filename is too long.

I have a simple div with an `ondrop` event handler

```
contentDiv.ondragover = uploadDragOver;
contentDiv.ondragenter = uploadDragEnter;
contentDiv.ondragleave = uploadDragLeave;
contentDiv.ondragend = uploadDragEnd;
contentDiv.ondrop = readItems;

...

function readItems(e) {
   const items = e.dataTransfer.items;
   console.log(items);
}
```

Comment: Try to show some of your code..

Comment: @NielsBosman Question updated. I have very simple DnD setup.

Answer (score 0):

After spending more time investigating and looking for a solution, I came across https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/test-if-dragenterdragover-event-contains-files/ which was my golden ticket!

I added a similar method to my DnD code. Now when I try dragging a file with a crazy path length, I can spit out "allowed to drop" or "not allowed to drop" type message.